# How do I update a relationship in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a subscription like this.

```
defmodule Rebirth.Subscription do
  use Rebirth.Web, :model

  schema "subscriptions" do
    ...
    belongs_to :user, Rebirth.User
    ...
  end

  ...

  def update_user(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
    |> cast_assoc(:user, required: false)    
  end
end
```

I want to associate a user to the subscription

So I tried

```
Rebirth.Subscription.update_user(subscription, %{user_id: 1})
```

or

```
Rebirth.Subscription.update_user(subscription, %{user: user})
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
** (ArgumentError) unknown assoc `user` in `cast_assoc`
```

How do I update the user_id?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same problem. :/

Comment: I haven't found a way to fix it yet, but digging around, I isolated the problem to `Ecto.Changeset.cast_relation/4`. Specifically, `Map.get(types, key)`. The association is not one of the models "types".

Comment: Well, my "it's the middle of the night and I'm tired of this" solution is to remove the `cast_assoc` and add `user_id` to the list of required params. It's a decent temporary workaround.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`cast_assoc` is used to "cast associated model" and **can be used only with `has_one` and `has_many`**. `belongs_to` relation defines the foreign id in the model where it is invoked. `has_many` and `has_one` rely on "the other" object having foreign key.

In case you are creating object that has many other objects it makes sense to check all of them if they are valid. `cast_assoc` will invoke `cast` in their respective modules.

Your user can have many subscriptions (probably, I am guessing here), so it doesn't make sense to create user when creating subscription and check if the user is valid via `cast_assoc`. Usually in this case the user will exist in database already.

In your case you only want to check if associated model exists in the cast, so you should use:

```
|> assoc_constraint(:user)
```

This does not validate user, but checks if given `user_id` exists in the database. Now, when you want to update the subscription for a user you can do this:

```
user = Repo.get(User, id)
subscription = Ecto.build_assoc(user, :subscriptions, other_fields_as_map)
```

Note it requires `has_one` or `has_many` on the user model.

Or you can simply update the user id as you tried before:

```
Rebirth.Subscription.update_user(subscription, %{user_id: 1})
```

and this time it will check the database if given user id exists, but You won't be able to pass entire user object here.

And if you want to update associated user, you will have to do it explicitly in two steps. a) get the user, b) update the user using changeset defined in its module.

Final note, if you don't make separate validation for updating users (and I don't think you should in this scenario), it would be good to rename the function from `update_user` to `changeset`. The same changeset can be used for creating and updating models.

Comment: Thanks!   Does this mean that the only way to set the user on a subscription rather than the subscriptions on a user is to set the user_id?     If I'm not wrong, this makes a new subscription, right: Ecto.build_assoc(user, :subscriptions, other_fields_as_map) ?

Comment: That is correct. It wouldn't make sense to set the user on subscription because it is the user who can have many subscriptions. And yes, `build_assoc` will create new subscription with `user_id` set. This is just a shorthand for getting the id and setting it on subscription manually also aware of associations.